# Is this the right site to ask about how to approach testing of my Azure Logic App?

Tags: discussion

I was burnt a few times when asked a question on a wrong SE site, so could I get a confirmation that the following question will be on-topic on this site?

> How do I approach testing an instance of an Azure Logic App?
>
> As far as I understand, I can write integration/end-to-end tests, and probably won't be able to write unit tests for the lack of a local execution environment and good targets for *unit* testing specifically. Things are complicated by the fact that Azure Logic App is expressed in JSON (as opposed to directly executable Node.js/Go/Python/... code as in AWS Lambda or other "serverless" solutions).
>
> If I can only end-to-end test, it will surely make my development cycle much much longer compared to developing "regular" software. I hate this a lot because this will affect the planning & delivery schedule, developer efficiency, solution quality, and customer satisfaction. It is very hard for me to imagine effective counter-measures that will soften the negative effects of long development cycle and absence of low level tests.

---

IMO, the question is on-topic for this site. Am I right or wrong?

The Help Center says in "Asking":

> If you have a question about...
>
> - software development methods and **practices**
> - ...
> - **quality assurance and testing**
> - ...
>
> ...then you're *probably* in the right place to ask your question.

Comment: It's a bit broad.  Can you make the question more specific?  Otherwise, it amounts to "How do I test Azure applications," a subject that could fill an entire book.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I understand that it's fairly broad, but I'm interested in approaches, and techniques. And this site _is_ about `software development methods and practices`. So, if not the site, what would be the better place to look for the answer? Just search in Google? (I see how this broad question may invalidate answers over time).

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion, your question could be on-topic. However, I cannot guarantee for other members of this community. Moreover, I think the question could be improved:

- asking about one very specific technology of one specific vendor has a smell of asking the community here for vendor support, which is [frowned up here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).
- moreover, I am not sure if you will really find the experts here for this specific technology, Stackoverflow might be the better place for this. If if you could reword your question in a more general fashion, asking "about problems of unit-testing of cloud-based applications - with the specific example of Azure Logic App", and describe "Azure Logic App" to the point where someone who is a software engineer, but not an expert in this special technology might give you an answer, then I guess chances are much higher you will get an answer here.
- your final paragraph sounds more like a rant, and it does not add any additional information or context to give you a better answer. So better remove it from the question

Comment: Thank you for a response Doc ;) Would you recommend reshaping my question into a more general "how to test declarative code based workflows that run in cloud" and post it here (using Azure Logic Apps as an example), or ask a very vendor-specific question on StackOverflow? I think, my question is more about the approaches, ideas, and practices, rather than App Logic specifically.

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko: you can shape your question to the site you prefer, or ask two different questions, one on each site, as long as they are clearly different enough for not being interpreted as crosspost. And you don't need anyones permission for that - don't overthink this, the worst thing which can happen is your question gets downvoted and closed, so you lose some virtual reputation points on a free site, that's not the end of the world.

Comment: I care about my reputation a lot, you know. /sarcasm Anyways. Will post something. Thanks again!